# PHP опциональная опция

Tags: php, yii2

Есть следующий код:

```
$form->field($model, 'test')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'tags' => true,
        'allowClear' => true,
    ],

    'options' => [
        'autocomplete' => 'off',
        'multiple' => true,
        'value' => [$test_var],
    ],
]);
```

Интересует, как сделать параметр `value` опциональным, т.е. чтобы если `$test_var !== null`, то параметр добавлялся, если нет, то и параметра не должно быть. Пытаюсь сделать что-то вроде:

```
$form->field($model, 'test')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'tags' => true,
        'allowClear' => true,
    ],

    'options' => [
        'autocomplete' => 'off',
        'multiple' => true,

        // Пытался так
        ($test_var !== null) ?? 'value' => [$test_var],

        // И так тоже пытался
        if ($test_var !== null) {
            'value' => [$test_var];
        }
    ],
]);
```

Но так это не работает :(
Как можно реализовать подобное?

Понимаю, что если `$test_var` в первом примере не существует, то ничего не будет вставлено. Однако интересует именно опциональность параметра.

Comment: либо array_merge (или проще даже конкатенация с тернарным оператором), либо определите массив параметров до вызова метода и добавьте там if с проверкой условия и добавления элемента в массив

Comment: а-ля `'options' => [some options] + ( is_null($test) ? [] : ['value' => $test] )`

Answer (score 1):

обычный путь будет выглядеть таким образом

```
$options = [....];
if (...condition...) {
    $options['value'] = $test;
}

$this->field(..., [
   'options' => $options,
]);
```

естественно просто так никаких `if`-ов посреди массива написать нельзя, как вы пытаетесь это сделать.

Однако можно несколько упростить, особенно с учетом того, что вам массив ассоциативный, то добавить конкатенацию массивов с условным (тернарным) оператором, где вам нужно в зависимости от условия вернуть либо пустой массив, либо нужное значение

```
'options' => [...options ....]
        + ( expr ? ['value' => $value] : [] )
```

Comment: Стоит заметить, что несколько упрощать не надо :-) Вариант с if уже простой и понятный.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин оно скорее укоротить, чем упростить.